# Z-Index for a child div outside of parent div stack

Tags: html, css

I have a div structure where I need to show some elements over my popup where it is inside another div element.

For example : I have a popup which is aligned on the top of page where I have to show site logo on top of popup which is in another container.

Below is the HTML structure :

`

```
<body>
    <div class="page-wrapper">
        <header>
            <div class="logo"></div>
        </header>
    </div>
    <div class="popup"></div>
<style>
    .popup {
        z-index: 2;
    }

    .logo {
        z-index: 3;
    }
</style>
</body>
```

`

Comment: read until the end of the duplicate and you will find 3D tricks to achieve this